# Symfony 2 + deploy : bootstrap.php.cache(861) error = Kernel->buildContainer()

Tags: deployment, symfony-2.1

I have just deployed my symfony 2.1.8 app into the server, by I have this error

```
0 app/bootstrap.php.cache(861): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() 
1 app/bootstrap.php.cache(573): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() 
2 app/bootstrap.php.cache(616): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() 
3 web/app.php(22): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
4 {main}
```

When I have deployed my application using Capifony, there was no problem.

HELP please

Comment: thats only part of the trace, what's the actual error?

Comment: I have no error... I have a blank page...

Comment: Does somebody can give me its prod controler? I have Apc installed

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

It was because the app/log wasn't in 777 rights.

hope it helps some guy